# How to create these blocks using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I understand how to figure out the color scheme. I need help understanding the thought process around configuring the layout.

] https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVSwP.png

Comment: I would need a few more details to solve this problem. For starters, what do you mean by "these blocks"?

Comment: I forgot to upload the picture my apologies

Comment: Do you want to manually create these blocks or do you want to automatically do it?

Comment: Sorry, but I could not understand what you are asking exactly. Can you explain a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

That’s a great layout candidate for CSS Grid.

Good place to start: https://gridbyexample.com/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Create a `<div>` element for each block, measure the sizes and positions of each block in your image and style your blocks in CSS accordingly.

Example: (not exactly replicating your image, just an example)

```css
#container {
  background: bisque;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
}

#block--1 {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 10px; //defines distance from top edge of container
  left: 10px; //defines distance from left edge of container
}

#block--2 {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 65px;
  left: 10px;
}

#block--3 {
  background: grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 105px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 115px;
}
#block--4 {
  background: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 105px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="block" id="block--1"></div>
  <div class="block" id="block--2"></div>
  <div class="block" id="block--3"></div>
  <div class="block" id="block--4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this helps me a lot!

Comment: @jahn1228 feel free to accept my answer if it helped for you!

Answer (score 0):

in my example, we are going to set the background color without a color code
we are going to do the following details:

```css
 #block{
   
   bacground-color: red;
   width:150px;
   height:150px;
   
   }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <title>document</title>
  </head>
   <body>
   <div id="block"></div>
   </body>
 </html>
```